# Rails console not working. Getting this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
16: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
15: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:381:in `start'
14: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:381:in `new'
13: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:410:in `initialize'
12: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:410:in `new'
11: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/context.rb:91:in `initialize'
10: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/extend-command.rb:242:in `save_history='
 9: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:45:in `save_history='
 8: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `init_save_history'
 7: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:21:in `extend'
 6: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:65:in `extended'
 5: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `load_history'
 4: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:75:in `open'
 3: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block in load_history'
 2: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `each'
 1: from /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in load_history'
/home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76:in `<<': string contains null byte (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking the source code at [`save-history.rb:76`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_0/lib/irb/ext/save-history.rb#L76) it seems that it has issues with your history file. I would try deleting the IRB history file(s). According to [`IRB#rc_file`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_5_0/lib/irb/init.rb#L240-L272) it can be in multiple places

If your `HOME` environment is set:

```
rm ~/.irb_history
```

If not then from the working directory:

```
rm .irb_history irb.history _irb_history '$irb_history`
```

Comment: Is it stopping with the same stack trace? Could you modify `save-history.rb` that it prints out the filename?

Comment: I have modified /home/hman01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/ext/save-history.rb:76. Files. It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the save-history.rb file.

```
f.each {|l| HISTORY << l.gsub("\u0000", '').chomp}.
```

Now it is working.